# Allow me to move comments on a post to the question when converting an answer to an edit

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

There are a number of times where a user will erroneously post what should be an edit on an answer.

A number of those times, there are other users that will still follow up the entire question on the answer that should have been an edit to the original post.

Currently, the "convert to edit" tool only converts the answer to an edit.  It blows away all the comments on the answer.

There is a workaround, but it's *very* ugly and cumbersome:

- Click on the answer to go to the page, taking me out of the moderator queue (which *no* operation should *ever* make me do).  If I convert to an edit, or convert the answer to a comment on the question, I've lost the flag and the answer, so I have to be *on the page*.
- Convert the answer to an edit.
- Undelete the answer.
- Convert the answer to a comment, moving all the comments on it.
- Delete the comment that was the original answer in the comments on the question.

A checkbox that would allow me to move all the comments on the answer along with the edit reduce the above steps to a single step.

Comment: It's clear that the "convert to edit" feature was [not well thought out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285548/222992) before implementation, and that fixing it is a very low priority, since it affects only a tiny number of users. I, too, run across this problem regularly.