# Moderator tool to convert an answer into an edit to the question should take labeling for links into account

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

I (as a mod) added [that answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1540739/176217) (you need 10k to see) as a complementary edit to the [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1540712/176217). The content of question was simply added to the question. Since they both - the question and the deleted answer - had images and link sections for them, after the supplementary edit was made only the link `[1]` from the question was used to render the image. As a result, the same image was rendered twice.

(Unfortunately, I made a manual edit during the grace period and hence you can't see that revision in list.)

To fix that issue the logic of "add an answer as supplementary edit to the question" should check the numbered links from the question and automatically fix numbering from the answer before the moving answer's content as an edit into the question's body.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so I have no experience with the feature, but how smart/dumb is the feature to turn an answer into an edit? Is it just adding the answer text below the question text, possibly with a separator between them, or is it handled in a smarter way?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Here's an [example case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4460489/revisions) (revision 4). It adds a horizontal line.

Comment: It's not only numbers, but custom text labels too. If the source and target posts use the same link label, the same problem will occur.

Comment: @Sonic could you please clarify situation about "link label"? What us "link label" in that case?

Comment: The link references do not have to be numbers - they can be any text. As an example: `[Link text][custom]` and later in the post, `[custom]: https://example.com/`. If both posts are using a link with the label `custom`, the same bug will occur. Another way is `[Link text]` and later in the post `[Link text]: https://example.com/`. I've edited your post to use both of these.

Comment: @Sonic Now it's clear, thanks. BTW for some reason [revision 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTKTa.png) doesn't render any change for me, weird.

Comment: It looks like this was [reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74998/323179), but doesn't work for posts with complicated formatting.

Comment: @Laurel `convert-to-comment` is different than `convert-to-edit`. My post is about latter.

Comment: This seems more like a [tag:feature-request] rather than a [tag:bug]. It's not something that's going wrong or which isn't working the way it was intended (i.e. the way you desire). It's *new capability* that you're asking to be implemented. Currently, that feature does exactly what it says it does: converts the answer to an edit to the question. It's, currently, expected that the moderator will verify that the added Markdown text works within the question.

Comment: I just discovered that this was already reported a long time ago: [Convert to edit feature messes up link numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245260/convert-to-edit-feature-messes-up-link-numbers)

Comment: @Sonic don't forget to change BR to FR on the found one as well.